# ARKit insert VC capture events Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, arkit

I put a VC inside a sceneView: ARSCNView

but the events of the SecondVC doesnt work I need change te text when the user press the button here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate,ARSessionDelegate {

   let vc = SecondVC()
    var viewVC = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

// I Get te reference to my view

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"SecondVC") as! SecondVC
        viewVC = viewController.view

        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.session.delegate=self

    }
}
```

And I trigger the event when I detect an anchor and put the VC in the scene

```
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {


      if self.detectedDataAnchor?.identifier == anchor.identifier {

              let node = SCNNode()
               let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.2, height: 0.2)
                plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = viewVC
                let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
                planeNode.opacity = 0
                node.addChildNode(planeNode)
              return node
       }
    return nil
}
```

In my SecondVC class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func pressButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        label.text = "I changed"
    }
```

But the action never is called in the main view  :(

[image: Arkit image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution

1 I created a xib file
2 Get access to file 
3 Show in the scene as follows:

```
let node = SCNNode()
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.2, height: 0.2)
            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = viewToShow
            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)

return node
```

and works! when tap a button I can change the text